# Saving passwords and completing autofill user names on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, password-management, auto-form-fill

Usually Google Chrome asks me if I want to save the password to a site. This is great, but it does not ask me on all sites. How Do I get it to save passwords on those sites where the popup question doesn't appear? AND,
after I download some sites, several user names pop up from me to choose from. How do I permanently eliminate those that are not correct?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question some sites can disable this or tell the browser to now allow this for security reasons (like a financial institution).

To manage those that do allow it go to Menu -> Settings -> Show Advanced Settings

In the Passwords and forms section click on 'Manage saved passwords'

[image: passwords]